# junit test: configuration file with path variable to the resources

Tags: java, file, testing, junit, configuration

I have an AttributesLoader class which picks a configuration file, retrieves variables and sets it's values to objects.

Example:

```
   if (validatePropertyValue(configuration.getString(PROPERTY_RECORD_LIMIT))) {
                extractionAttributesBuilder.setRecordLimit(configuration.getInt(PROPERTY_RECORD_LIMIT));
            }
```

Code works fine but I struggle to write test for some of the attributes.
Because the code picks up a file, I have a cfg file in my src/test/resources.
One of the properties is a path to a directory..

I tried doing it this way:

```
path=new File(AttributesLoaderTest.class.getResource("/extractPath").getPath()));
```

but it doesn't work because it looks for a path:
new File(AttributesLoaderTest.class.getResource("/extractPath").getPath())); which is useless..

My question is:

How can I provide a path in a file to my src/test/resources directory without it being hardoced?

```
path=/extractPath
```

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to pass the root as a system property and use that to compose the path to the file.

Within the `pom.xml` you would for example set the system property as follows:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <resourcesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/src/config/</resourcesDirectory>
        [...]
      </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

and within the JUnit class you could then have:

```
path=new File(AttributesLoaderTest.class.getResource(System.getProperty("resourcesDirectory") + "/extractPath").getPath()));
```

*NOTE:* Haven't tested the code above so might contain some faults.

Comment: So for the test purpose I would need to hardocode the root path to my resources? How will this work if build can be performed on different servers every time?

Comment: Extended the answer with an example on how it might be done